# How to send a URL request in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

I need to call a URL with parameters from a method in rails. How do I call the URL in rails? And example is that in the method, I want to call this URL request: [www.example.com?name=parameter01&password=parameter02](http://www.example.com?name=parameter01&password=parameter02)

How do I call this type of URL method in rails?

Comment: You mean that the server initiates a get request to that address?

Comment: Yup.. I'm want the server to initiate a post/get request to the address

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try this : http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html?

An example :

```
require 'net/http'
uri = URI('http://example.com/index.html?key=value')
req = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
puts req #show result
```

Comment: I tried that.. but got the following error: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)"

Comment: You have a problem with a firefwall or something like this. Test it with a `wget` or `curl` command (on *nix systems).